# Linebreak breaks file read

Tags: php, file, text, readfile

Im trying to read files with from the server. This works pretty well but i got a problem:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce
>   dignissim, magna sed egestas suscipit, tortor nunc lacinia felis, eget
>   tempus nunc neque non augue. Suspendisse ut turpis nulla. Suspendisse
>   eu nisi quis tortor porttitor elementum. Mauris id massa turpis.
>   Nullam scelerisque euismod sollicitudin.
>
> Nam imperdiet lorem nec mi posuere laoreet. Pellentesque sed metus
>   eget quam pulvinar imperdiet ut et diam. Maecenas molestie magna vitae
>   metus pretium posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. In ut libero nulla, sit
>   amet consequat lacus. Quisque ac lectus a libero venenatis placerat
>   sed ac metus. Aenean congue nunc non sapien vulputate tempus.

If i put a line break in the textfile it only reads the second paragraph. 
What is the best way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$file = "./textfiles_tips/woningmarkt.txt";
if (file_exists($file))
{
    $f = fopen($file, "r");

    while ( $line = fgets($f) )
    {
        $data['text'] = $line;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

$this->layout->buildPage('main/tips/woningmarkt', $data);
```

Comment: please show your code so that we help you to findout the bug

Comment: Does brake mean break?  A line break?  A newline character?  A pair of `<br>` tags?  A `<p>` tag?  Something else?  How are you reading the file?  How are you filtering it?  Without more specific information this question can't be reasonably answered.

Comment: edited. I mean the space between the 2 paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite `$data['text']` every line. Use `.=` to append instead of overwriting.
Before the loop use `$data['text'] = '';` to initialize it to an empty string.

```
$data['text'] = '';
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
    $data['text'] .= $line;
}
```

However, you can do it even easier using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents). Replace the whole code from `fopen` until the loop with this:

```
$data['text'] = file_get_contents($file);
```